How to connect Lora Module(in the pcp) to the LoRa Gateway, Model:LG01-N?
I'm working on connecting the sensors in the pcp to the LoRa gateway, model: LG01-N. To do this, I'll have to connect the LoRa module in the pcp to the LoRa gateway. I can't find any resource or method to do this.
I'm doing this to monitor the environment, so it's given that the LoRa module and LoRa gateway have to be connected over Wi-Fi. Also, I'll be using UART for the transmission.
Another student is working on the pcp first, so I don't exactly know which sensors or what he's done yet. I'm just interested in connecting the LoRa module (in pcp) to the LoRa gateway.

"so it's given that the LoRa module and LoRa gateway have to be connected over Wi-Fi." Errr no. They are connected over LoRa (or LoRaWAN)...
